# Access Denied for uploading files from file from a ec2 instance ubuntu apache server laravel app to s3 bucket. Works from Local Env

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

From laravel local app the upload to S3 bucket works completely fine. But with the same code and aws credentials. The file doesn't upload. Even the laravel fly system s3 generates the aws file link for the uploaded file. But when I go to the link it shows the following.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>4SVQ96YNNZMQY1GT</RequestId>
<HostId>IpOgS8erRF4yPsvpC8aNxmDRs6GRDHD1UNxO3n2M1S7ejWEoFPRw5g2jILxiUYtknN7EH2bHQTI=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Note that, from the local environment the file gets uploaded and the link shows the actual file.
I have also enabled ACL, and public access to my files from the s3 bucket.

I tried to add policies to directly upload the from ec2 to s3.

Comment: double check your api credentials and their permissions

Comment: They are correct. Because same credentials work from local environment.

Answer (score 0):

The bucket should be private. you have two options i go for option#2 (welll #1 too)

**1. Ask the Storage for a temp url, this way:**

Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($image, now()->addSeconds(120))

**2. Edit bucket permissions:**

By default block public access is set, so it wont work. Create a full access user and start removing permissions, until it gets grained.

**ALSO: Double check the .env AWS_xxxx values check if id,key,region,bucket path, etc. are fine.**

Comment: Block all public access is disabled, including all granular options. So everything is disabled.

Comment: Check the ALSO Section, double check env values or configmap if you are on kubernetes

Comment: How to see the ALSO section? The credentials are absolutely the same as my local, and they are working fine locally. Only fails when uploading from the ec2 instance laravel app.

Comment: After enabling public access to all my files now the error message is changed to this.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>organization_logos/muFW7LrmWYTtWcv3cYeUikFdRlHDNeFqaVQ6p4yk.png</Key>
<RequestId>WNNH6GWP4K06DQ5N</RequestId>
<HostId>QXinZSIKpqtQbSYa5y6VMam1eZYjWRGvNG6RxOsXd7mfsHsIrQsZOZBSYALHBIItx+vxYMyO0U4=</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: is this the correct path to the bucket + file ? organization_logos/muFW7LrmWYTtWcv3cYeUikFdRlHDNeFqaVQ6p4yk.png ????

Comment: This link and file is generated by Laravel Fly System. But it doesn't actually upload the file to S3. It does upload from local though, and the link shows the file.